# How to I run sandbox on my windows laptop?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

I've been trying to **learn about algorand from last few days**.

[image: Unable to setup Algorand Sandbox on my laptop]

I tried following tutorial on youtube, but I'm unable to set it up on my laptop.

**Nor I'm able to run docker & algorand daemons.**

**how do i set it up for windows?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yeah i was facing same problem earlier.

if you're finding it hard to Install & run sandbox.

Here's what you exactly need to do....

1. Make sure you've DockerDesktop Installed

   If not watch this video **from Algorand youtube playlist** to install it.

   [Here's link to official playlist by algorand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3d3VTlgMo8&list=PLpAdAjL5F75CNnmGbz9Dm_k-z5I6Sv9_x)
2. Make sure you've got **UBUNTU WSL (AKA Windows Subsystem Linux)** Installed

   if not **go to windows store & search ubuntu wsl > Install it**.
3. once you've **both docker & ubuntu WSL installed**

   you can simply open ubuntu in terminal

Now you'll need to clone sandbox.

Clone sandbox from github.

https://github.com/algorand/sandbox

once you've cloned sandbox.

you can run it by  using following command

```
./sandbox up
```

and Violla it works.